# How To Read User.Identity.Name?

Tags: c#, linq

How i can read the User.Identity.Name value, my gridview didn't show anythings. Need help.

```
//lblName.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
//string email = lblName.Text;
var result = from r in db.Orders
             where r.Email == Page.User.Identity.Name
             //join p in db.OrderLists on r.Order_ID equals p.Order_ID
             //join s in db.MenuItems on p.Item_ID equals s.Item_ID
             select r.DateTime;

GridView1.DataSource = result;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: window or web ? asp.net ?

Comment: I think this link will help you: http://forums.asp.net/t/1507047.aspx

Comment: What is the value of Page.User.Identity.Name you getting. Is it null if it is null then add this in web Config                                    <system.ServiceModel>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />

</system.ServiceModel>

Answer (score 1):

Try using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` !